# Can I specify css ::before selector style in Rails view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my **css** I have this:

```
.inner-class {
  content: '';
}

.inner-class:before {
  background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/500/500.jpg);
  content: '';
}
```

And in my view's **html.erb**, I have this:

```
<div class="outer-class">
  <div class="inner-class">
    ::before
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the ::before selector's properties using Rails. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
<div class="outer-class">
  <div class="inner-class" style:"background: url(<% image_path %>)">
    ::before
  </div>
</div>
```

However, that won't change the properties of inner-class:before. How do I do this?

Comment: you can't do it inline. Could append a style tag to head though

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is add an additional CSS class, and change the ::before pseudo there, then apply that class conditionally to the parent element.

1. Remove the `::before` text from your ERB.
2. Add a CSS class like so:

```
 .inner-class.do-something:before {
   background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/300/300.jpg);
   content: '';
```

3. Add in a conditional to your ERB like so:

```
 <div class="outer-class">
   <div class="inner-class" class="<% 'do-something' if my_condition %>">

   </div>
 </div>
```

## Edit

Based on your comment, you're looking for something more like this.  **Fair warning** this is probably the worst way to display an image dynamically in Rails I can imagine, and at this point I'd recommend you just have a separate element for your avatar image.

```
<div class='inner-class' data-image="<% ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(open(article.user.avatar_url) { |io| io.read }) %>"></div>
```

Your CSS would be

```
 .inner-class:before { 
   content: url(attr(data-image)); 
   height: 40px; 
   width: 40px;  /* Whatever the expected height and width of the image are */`
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps me in this particular situation. I want to generate the image dynamically in the view, rather than set it in the css. So, something like `<% article.user.avatar_url %>`  would be set as the background image in the ::before element.

Comment: I think I've decided to pursue another way of displaying the images after reading your comments, but I thought I'd try your method to see if I could get it to work. Trying it this way gives me an `uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Base64" error.

Comment: Did you `require 'base64'`?

Comment: At the top of whatever file you're using the ActiveSupport::Base64.

Comment: If that would be `article.rb' in this instance, then yes. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with how that works.